# How to call a function that is defined outside the scope in an Angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

Is there any way to call a function that is defined outside the scope in an [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)?

Suppose that I have an external file that is bundled via Browserify:

```
var dateUtils = require('./date-utils.js');
```

and I want to access the `dateUtils.nextMonth()` function from the Angular Expression like this:

```
"{{ dateUtils.nextMonth() }}"
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: $scope.dateUtils = dateUtils will expose the functions object

Comment: @Joaozito Polo What is the best practice? Expose it like you said or write a service?

Comment: If you will use in other places, its better to write a service or factory..

Comment: I particularly prefer to use the function on controller "scope.nextMonth = dateUtils.nextMonth() " because the angular will create a watch for your expression. Ok, for the string will be create also, but it's more simple to compare for angular.